# all functions working on click except .scrollTop or .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile, scrolltop

I'm struggling for long time for this issue...

The button **bio** needs to scroll to the top on click so the information is displayed correctly on the mobile device. This button has different functionalities. All the other functionalities work except for the scrollTop and its driving me crazy, why is this?

Actual website with the code working: http://cepods.com/about.php
The bio button on click should scroll the viewport to the top.

HTML:

```
<section class="main-block">
    <h1 class="a-title">about</h1>
    <section class="content-block scroll-pane">
        <article class="content-post">
            <div class="info info-1" id="info-1">
                <p>CEPODS creates commercial &amp; residential environments using shipping containers. Our aim is to create a community of enthusiast with each build of our unique modern designs.</p>
                <p>CEPODS are seen as efficient and effective pod styled units, when compared to other typical commercial spaces such as brick &amp; mortar, food trucks, tent rentals or temporary (pop-up) stores.</p>
                <p>CEPODS modern design standards are ideal for anyone interested in operating, marketing, advertising or expanding their presence by using innovative alternative commercial space with shipping containers. The ideal CEPODS clients -are small to large businesses, start-up, pop-up, 2nd store, test retail outlet, and advertising & marketing platforms. Our client base is also expanded to residential and lodging enthusiasts. Many more all welcome.</p>
                <p>CEPODS expertise is based in architecture, engineering, design/build, real estate, marketing, retail sales and small business management. Our team of professionals shares the same common passion; produce high quality modern design builds.</p>
                <h1>
                    <a href="#" class="text-btn bio" id="info-2-link" data-info="2">Bio<i class="icon-right-open-gal"></i></a>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="info info-2" id="info-2">
                <h1>Micro Spaces LLC</h1>
                <p>Executive Member: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="1">TIMOTHY DUNLAP/TIAN MAO</a></p>
                <p>Executive Member: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="2">ANDREW HAGUE II</a></p>
                <p>Director of Engineering: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="3">RICK DE LA GUARDIA</a></p>
                <p>Project Architect: <a href="#"class="pop-btn pop-link" data-popup="4">IBRAHIM GREENIDGE</a></p>
                <h1>
                    <a href="#" class="text-btn bio" id="info-1-link" data-info="1">about<i class="icon-right-open-gal"></i></a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".bio").click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/BKV68/

Comment: @David Huh! In the website it does not work, do you have any idea why? The code is correct, I double checked but never find the problem...

Comment: Seems like it has something todo with the `html, body { height: 100% }`, so the page is always at `scrollTop:0`.